# connecting postgresql codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to connect a postgres db but I get this error

my database.php file I have the default connection too add

```
$db['newdb'] = array(
        'dsn'   => 'pgsql:host=192.xxx.x.xxx;port=5432;dbname=dbname',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'dbdriver' => 'pgsql',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

here my modal

```
<?php
class Model extends CI_Model {

 private $db_b;

 function __construct(){
  $this->db_b = $this->load->database('newdb', TRUE);
 }


 public function getData()
 {

   $this->db_b->order_by('ad_reference_id', 'asc');
   $query = $this->db_b->get('table');
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
     return $query->result();
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```

I got this ERROR
    An Error Was Encountered

```
Invalid DB driver
```

Why is it not working? :(

Comment: change  **'dbdriver' => 'pgsql'**  to  **'dbdriver' => 'pdo'**

Answer (score 1):

You have designated a driver that does not exist with this

```
'dbdriver' => 'pgsql',
```

I think what you want is

```
'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
```

***Edit: Checking PHP configuration***

Create a controller called Info.php
Here's the code for it.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Info extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        phpinfo();
    }
}
```

Direct the browser to *yoursite.com/info* and search the resulting page for postgres.

Comment: Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Filename: /var/www/html/test/system/database/drivers/postgre/postgre_driver.php

Line Number: 154

Comment: Well that is weird because `pg_connect()` is a [PHP function](http://www.php.net/pg_connect).  You certain that your PHP has PostgreSQL installed?

Comment: how can I check that? I'm on linux Mint

Comment: See the added info in the answer.

Comment: could affect in the server they have php 5.0 and Im working with codeigniter 3.1.9

Comment: I believe that PHP 5.6 is the lowest version acceptable for 3.1.9